# How to count the number of occurrences in either of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple looking problem. I have a dataframe `df` with two columns. For each of the strings that occurs in either of these columns I would like to count the number of rows which has the symbol in either column.

E.g.

```
g k
a h
c i
j e
d i
i h
b b
d d
i a
d h
```

The following code works but is very inefficient.

```
for elem in set(df.values.flat):
    print elem, len(df.loc[(df[0] == elem) | (df[1] == elem)])


a 2
c 1
b 1
e 1
d 3
g 1
i 4
h 3
k 1
j 1
```

This is however very inefficient and my dataframe is large. The inefficiency comes from calling `df.loc[(df[0] == elem) | (df[1] == elem)]` separately for every distinct symbol in df.

Is there a fast way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly is `df.values.flat`? Are you just testing the entire df for membership of a list of characters?

Comment: @EdChum It just gives all the symbols in the dataframe.

Comment: @EdChum - check another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39437504/2901002)

Comment: @eleanora At some point we should wrap your real issue and stop circling back with all the trials and errors here. Basically you want to group by the two columns and count the number of pairs you have. That will give you the list of pairs that are non-zero and give you the counts of double countings rows. then you can just do value_counts on the first column, another on the second one, add those 2 numbers and subtract the groupby count results. It probably resolves your issues and the set of back and forth questions you post and delete and repost again. HTH

Comment: @Boud To be fair my question does include code and a full worked example. If anything is unclear please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loc` to filter out row level matches from `'col2'`, append the filtered `'col2'` values to `'col1'`, and then call `value_counts`:

```
counts = df['col1'].append(df.loc[df['col1'] != df['col2'], 'col2']).value_counts()
```

The resulting output:

```
i    4
d    3
h    3
a    2
j    1
k    1
c    1
g    1
b    1
e    1
```

Note: You can add `.sort_index()` to the end of the counting code if you want the output to appear in alphabetical order.

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a larger sample dataset:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

n = 10**5
data = np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), size=(n,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

def edchum(df):
    vals = np.unique(df.values)
    count = np.maximum(df['col1'].str.get_dummies().reindex_axis(vals, axis=1).fillna(0), df['col2'].str.get_dummies().reindex_axis(vals, axis=1).fillna(0)).sum()
    return count
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit df['col1'].append(df.loc[df['col1'] != df['col2'], 'col2']).value_counts()
10 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop

%timeit edchum(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.81 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you and the timings are very useful!

Comment: Is there a similarly elegant solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437504/how-to-count-rows-efficiently-with-one-pass-over-the-dataframe do you think?

Answer (score 2):

OK this is much trickier than I thought, not sure how this will scale but if you have a lot of repeating values then it will be more efficient than your current method, basically we can use `str.get_dummies` and reindex the columns from that result to generate a dummies df for all unique values, we can then use `np.maximal` on the 2 dfs and `sum` these:

```
In [77]:
t="""col1 col2
g k
a h
c i
j e
d i
i h
b b
d d
i a
d h"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True)
np.maximum(df['col1'].str.get_dummies().reindex_axis(vals, axis=1).fillna(0), df['col2'].str.get_dummies().reindex_axis(vals, axis=1).fillna(0)).sum()

Out[77]:
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    3
e    1
g    1
h    3
i    4
j    1
k    1
dtype: float64
```

vals here is  just the unique values:

```
In [80]:
vals = np.unique(df.values)
vals

Out[80]:
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure how to use that to get the counts for all the different symbols in the dataframe.  I think you need "header=None" too maybe in the read_csv line?

Comment: The "a b" is the header row, not input data in this case so you do _not_ want `header=None`. It would be clearer if they were called something else though!
What do you mean how do you get the counts? You just access the result, e.g. `result = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).sum(axis=1).astype(int)` `print(r['d'])` will give you 4

Comment: I don't think this quite gives the expected result.  The code in the OP counts the number of rows in which a symbol appears, but this just counts the number of symbols.  The difference being in rows where both symbols are identical.  Consider the `b b` row, the code in the OP only counts this as one occurrence for `b`, but this answer counts it as two occurrences.

Comment: root is right that this doesn't give the  correct answer. Compare to the table in my question. See "b 1" for example.

Comment: can you check updated answer, I think I understand what you want now