# Vectorized way to count occurrences of string in either of two columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a problem that is *similar* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451385/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-either-of-two-columns), but just different enough that it can't be solved with the same solution...

I've got two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
names = ['jack', 'jill', 'jane', 'joe', 'ben', 'beatrice']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_a':np.random.choice(names, 20), 'ID_b':np.random.choice(names,20)})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':names})

>>> df1
        ID_a      ID_b
0        joe       ben
1        ben      jack
2       jane       joe
3        ben      jill
4        ben  beatrice
5       jill       ben
6       jane       joe
7       jane      jack
8       jane      jack
9        ben      jane
10       joe      jane
11      jane      jill
12  beatrice       joe
13       ben       joe
14      jill  beatrice
15       joe  beatrice
16  beatrice  beatrice
17  beatrice      jane
18      jill       joe
19       joe       joe

>>> df2
         ID
0      jack
1      jill
2      jane
3       joe
4       ben
5  beatrice
```

What I'd like to do is add in a column to `df2`, with the **count** of rows in `df1` where the given name can be found in **either** column `ID_a` or `ID_b`, resulting in this:

```
>>> df2
         ID  count
0      jack      3
1      jill      5
2      jane      8
3       joe      9
4       ben      7
5  beatrice      6
```

This loop gets what I need, but is inefficient for large dataframes, and if someone could suggest an alternative, nicer solution, I'd be very grateful:

```
df2['count'] = 0

for idx,row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.loc[idx, 'count'] = len(df1[(df1.ID_a == row.ID) | (df1.ID_b == row.ID)])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added more options. Take @jpp's timings with a grain of salt, timings really mean nothing when you are benchmarking solutions for a handful of rows. You may want to try these solutions on much larger dataframes, and then you'll really see a difference.

Comment: I noticed, I really appreciate it. My actual dataframe is obviously much bigger than what I posted, but not *huge*, so I can afford to lose out a little bit on efficiency for the sake of elegance. However, my original solution seemed both inefficient *and* inelegant, which is why I wanted some input...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "either" part complicates things, but should still be doable.

---

**Option 1**
Since other users decided to turn this into a speed-race, here's mine:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(x) for x in df1.values.tolist()))
df2['count'] = df2['ID'].map(Counter(c))
df2

         ID  count
0      jack      3
1      jill      5
2      jane      8
3       joe      9
4       ben      7
5  beatrice      6
```

```
176 µs ± 7.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

**Option 2**
(Original answer) `stack` based

```
c = df1.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().count(level=1)
```

Or,

```
c = df1.stack().reset_index(level=0).drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()
```

Or,

```
v = df1.stack()
c = v.groupby([v.index.get_level_values(0), v]).count().count(level=1)
# c = v.groupby([v.index.get_level_values(0), v]).nunique().count(level=1)
```

And,

```
df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(c)
df2

         ID  count
0      jack      3
1      jill      5
2      jane      8
3       joe      9
4       ben      7
5  beatrice      6
```

---

**Option 3**
`repeat`-based Reshape and counting

```
v = pd.DataFrame({
        'i' : df1.values.reshape(-1, ), 
        'j' : df1.index.repeat(2)
    })
c = v.loc[~v.duplicated(), 'i'].value_counts()

df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(c)
df2

         ID  count
0      jack      3
1      jill      5
2      jane      8
3       joe      9
4       ben      7
5  beatrice      6
```

---

**Option 4**
`concat` + `mask`

```
v = pd.concat(
    [df1.ID_a, df1.ID_b.mask(df1.ID_a == df1.ID_b)], axis=0
).value_counts()

df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(v)
df2

         ID  count
0      jack      3
1      jill      5
2      jane      8
3       joe      9
4       ben      7
5  beatrice      6
```

Comment: Appreciate all the answers! I have to say, I actually like your original answer the best, as far as readability. Might not be the fastest, but like I said, with a `df` of the modest size that I'm working with, it does the job just fine.

Comment: @sacul, I would add that all of cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answers (and your whole workflow) *could* be trivially improved by using categorical data. It's something we *all* missed in the first round of answers. Incidentally, it also demonstrates why it's often a good idea to keep such questions unaccepted a day or two.

Comment: @jpp, thanks for all your answers too, I appreciate it a ton, and if there were an option to accept two answers, I would accept yours too. I've gotta read up on [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), it's a dtype I'm really not familiar with!

Answer (score 6):

Below are a couple of ways based on `numpy` arrays. Benchmarking below.

**Important**: Take these results with a grain of salt. Remember, performance is dependent on your data, environment and hardware. In your choice, you should also consider readability / adaptability.

**Categorical data**: The superb performance with categorical data in `jp2` (i.e. factorising strings to integers via an internal dictionary-like structure) is data-dependent, but if it works it should be applicable across all the below algorithms with good performance *and* memory benefits.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

# Tested on python 3.6.2 / pandas 0.20.3 / numpy 1.13.1

%timeit original(df1, df2)   # 48.4 ms per loop
%timeit jp1(df1, df2)        # 5.82 ms per loop
%timeit jp2(df1, df2)        # 2.20 ms per loop
%timeit brad(df1, df2)       # 7.83 ms per loop
%timeit cs1(df1, df2)        # 12.5 ms per loop
%timeit cs2(df1, df2)        # 17.4 ms per loop
%timeit cs3(df1, df2)        # 15.7 ms per loop
%timeit cs4(df1, df2)        # 10.7 ms per loop
%timeit wen1(df1, df2)       # 19.7 ms per loop
%timeit wen2(df1, df2)       # 32.8 ms per loop

def original(df1, df2):
    for idx,row in df2.iterrows():
        df2.loc[idx, 'count'] = len(df1[(df1.ID_a == row.ID) | (df1.ID_b == row.ID)])
    return df2

def jp1(df1, df2):
    for idx, item in enumerate(df2['ID']):
        df2.iat[idx, 1] = np.sum((df1.ID_a.values == item) | (df1.ID_b.values == item))
    return df2

def jp2(df1, df2):
    df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].astype('category')
    df1['ID_a'] = df1['ID_a'].astype('category')
    df1['ID_b'] = df1['ID_b'].astype('category')
    for idx, item in enumerate(df2['ID']):
        df2.iat[idx, 1] = np.sum((df1.ID_a.values == item) | (df1.ID_b.values == item))
    return df2

def brad(df1, df2):
    names1, names2 = df1.values.T
    v2 = df2.ID.values
    mask1 = v2 == names1[:, None]
    mask2 = v2 == names2[:, None]
    df2['count'] = np.logical_or(mask1, mask2).sum(axis=0)
    return df2

def cs1(df1, df2):
    c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(x) for x in df1.values.tolist()))
    df2['count'] = df2['ID'].map(Counter(c))
    return df2

def cs2(df1, df2):
    v = df1.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().count(level=1)
    df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(v)
    return df2

def cs3(df1, df2):
    v = pd.DataFrame({
            'i' : df1.values.reshape(-1, ), 
            'j' : df1.index.repeat(2)
        })
    c = v.loc[~v.duplicated(), 'i'].value_counts()

    df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(c)
    return df2

def cs4(df1, df2):
    v = pd.concat(
        [df1.ID_a, df1.ID_b.mask(df1.ID_a == df1.ID_b)], axis=0
    ).value_counts()

    df2['count'] = df2.ID.map(v)
    return df2

def wen1(df1, df2):
    return pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(level=0,axis=1).gt(0).sum().loc[df2.ID]

def wen2(df1, df2):
    return pd.Series(Counter(list(chain(*list(map(set,df1.values)))))).loc[df2.ID]
```

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

names = ['jack', 'jill', 'jane', 'joe', 'ben', 'beatrice']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_a':np.random.choice(names, 10000), 'ID_b':np.random.choice(names, 10000)})    

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':names})

df2['count'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the options, and I'm surprised by the times! I would have thought that the `.stack().groupby...` method would have been fastest...

Comment: It isn't exactly "vectorised" as the question asked, but still an answer. @sacul Sadly, stack is stupidly slower than it needs to be. I've been hoping these guys would work on optimising that code in a future release. It's so useful, but is not as fast as it can be. Sometimes elegant one liners come at a price.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, completely agree - vectorised solutions should be faster. But currently there are large relative overheads for even simple tasks. Another trivial one is `pd.Series.replace` with `dict` - where pandas goes out of its way to remove any performance benefit.

Comment: would you mind test timing for my solution as well ? Thank you

Comment: Since you're keeping track of timings, can you please update with all 3 new options I've added?

Answer (score 3):

By using `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(level=0,axis=1).gt(0).sum().loc[df2.ID]
Out[614]: 
jack        3
jill        5
jane        8
joe         9
ben         7
beatrice    6
dtype: int64
```

I think this should be fast ...

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

pd.Series(Counter(list(chain(*list(map(set,df1.values)))))).loc[df2.ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution where you effectively do the nested "in" loop by expanding dimensionality of `ID` from `df2` to take advantage of NumPy broadcasting:

```
>>> def count_names(df1, df2):
...     names1, names2 = df1.values.T
...     v2 = df2.ID.values[:, None]
...     mask1 = v2 == names1
...     mask2 = v2 == names2
...     df2['count'] = np.logical_or(mask1, mask2).sum(axis=1)
...     return df2


>>> %timeit -r 5 -n 1000 count_names(df1, df2)
144 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r 5 -n 1000 jp(df1, df2)
224 µs ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r 5 -n 1000 cs(df1, df2)
238 µs ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r 5 -n 1000 wen(df1, df2)
921 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The shape of the masks will be `(len(df1), len(df2))`.

Comment: This is not a speed race. Sadly, one user took it upon themselves to make it one.

Comment: Updated with something that should be pretty scalable for large frames @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: "Post the sexiest solution you can think of"? :D

Comment: @jpp Interestingly, option 1 is the one I despise. It isn't nice, or elegant. It just is. If you ask me, I still stick to Option 2, because that's really what came to my mind first. It's pretty intuitive. There's another piResque option involving factorize and bincount that I later removed (I mean, 4 options is already overkill) but I really liked that one too.