# Loop on pandas dataframe over unique values only

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
DB      Table   Column  Format

Retail  Orders  ID      INTEGER
Retail  Orders  Place   STRING
Dept    Sales   ID      INTEGER
Dept    Sales   Name    STRING
```

I want to loop on the Tables, while generating a SQL for creating the tables. e.g.

```
create table Retail.Orders ( ID INTEGER, Place STRING)
create table Dept.Sales ( ID INTEGER, Name STRING)
```

What I've already done is get distinct db & tables using `drop_duplicate` and then for each table apply a filter and concatenate the strings to create a sql.

```
def generate_tables(df_cols):
    tables = df_cols.drop_duplicates(subset=[KEY_DB, KEY_TABLE])[[KEY_DB, KEY_TABLE]]

    for index, row in tables.iterrows():
        db = row[KEY_DB]
        table = row[KEY_TABLE]

        print("DB: " + db)
        print("Table: " + table)

        sql = "CREATE TABLE " + db + "." + table + " ("
        cols = df_cols.loc[(df_cols[KEY_DB] == db) & (df_cols[KEY_TABLE] == table)]
        for index, col in cols.iterrows():
            sql += col[KEY_COLUMN] + " " + col[KEY_FORMAT] + ", "

        sql += ")"

        print(sql)
```

Is there a better approach to iterate over the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I would do it. First create a dictionary via `df.itertuples` [more efficient than `df.iterrows`], then use `str.format` to include the values seamlessly.

Uniqueness is guaranteed in dictionary construction by using `set`.

I also convert to a generator so you can iterate it efficiently if you wish; it's always possible to exhaust the generator via `list` as below.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for row in df.itertuples():
    d[(row[1], row[2])].add((row[3], row[4]))

def generate_tables_jp(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield 'CREATE TABLE {0}.{1} ({2})'\
              .format(k[0], k[1], ', '.join([' '.join(i) for i in v]))

list(generate_tables_jp(d))
```

Result:

```
['CREATE TABLE Retail.Orders (ID INTEGER, Place STRING)',
 'CREATE TABLE Dept.Sales (ID INTEGER, Name STRING)']
```

Answer (score 1):

If looping is what you want, then yes .iterrows() is the most efficient way to get through a pandas frame. EDIT: From other answer, and link here - [Does iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues) - I believe that .itertuples() is actually a better generator for performance.

However, depending on the size of the dataframe you might be better off using some pandas groupby functions to assist

consider something like this

```
# Add a concatenation of the column name and format
df['col_format'] =  df['Column'] + ' ' + df['Format']

# Now create a frame which is the groupby of the DB/Table rows and 
# concatenates the tuples of col_format correctly
y1 = (df.groupby(by=['DB', 'Table'])['col_format']
        .apply(lambda x: '(' + ', '.join(x) + ')'))

# Reset the index to bring the keys/indexes back in as columns
y2 = y1.reset_index()

# Now create a Series of all of the SQL statements
all_outs = 'Create Table ' + y2['DB'] + '.' + y2['Table'] + ' ' + y2['col_format']

# Look at them!
all_outs.values
Out[44]: 
array(['Create Table Dept.Sales (ID INTEGER, Name STRING)',
       'Create Table Retail.Orders (ID INTEGER, Place STRING)'], dtype=object)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this answer (and upvote it), but be careful. `groupby` is not *always* faster than `itertuples` for large dataframes, e.g. look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413710/9209546). Remember that `groupby` should have O(n log n) complexity, but its performance is often driven by the function, and `lambda` is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first assemble the info per line in an extra column, and then use `groupby.sum`

```
queries = df[KEY_COLUMN] + ' ' + df[KEY_FORMAT] + ', '
queries.index = df.set_index(index_labels).index
```

> ```
> DB      Table 
> Retail  Orders      ID INTEGER, 
>         Orders    Place STRING, 
> Dept    Sales       ID INTEGER, 
>         Sales      Name STRING, 
> dtype: object
> ```

```
queries = queries.groupby(index_labels).sum().str.strip(', ')
```

> ```
> DB      Table 
> Dept    Sales      ID INTEGER, Name STRING
> Retail  Orders    ID INTEGER, Place STRING
> dtype: object
> ```

```
def format_queries(queries):
    query_pattern = 'CREATE TABLE %s.%s (%s)'
    for (db, table), text in queries.items():# idx, table, text
        query = query_pattern % (db, table, text)
        yield query
list(format_queries(queries))
```

> ```
> ['CREATE TABLE Dept.Sales (ID INTEGER, Name STRING)',
>  'CREATE TABLE Retail.Orders (ID INTEGER, Place STRING)']
> ```

This way you don't need the `lambda`. I don't know whether this approach or the `itertuples` will be fastest