# Using Pandas value.counts() to get one value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is there a way to get counts of only specific item in a column?

To clarify, say I use:

```
countDat = df['country'].value_counts()
```

Then I'll get something like:

```
Australia  35
Brazil 32
USA 93
```

... and so on

Is there a way to only extract counts of Brazil? I just need the number 32 extracted from `countDat`.

I know `countDat[1]` will give Brazil but is there a way to search it through the key 'Brazil'?

Comment: `df.loc[df.country == 'Brazil', 'country'].count()`

Comment: .. did you _try_ `countDat["Brazil"]`?

Comment: oh both works! thank you . I thought I tried Brazil ... apprently I did something wrong. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to drop down to `numpy`:

```
res = (df['country'].values == 'Brazil').sum()
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413710/9209546) for benchmarking results from a similar problem.

You should see better performance if you are using [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), which also has other benefits.

Answer (score 3):

consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(country=np.array('AUS BRA USA'.split()).repeat([35, 32, 93])))
```

and value counts

```
countDat = df['country'].value_counts()

countDat

USA    93
AUS    35
BRA    32
Name: country, dtype: int64
```

---

#### per @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

```
df.loc[df.country == 'BRA', 'country'].count()

32
```

---

#### per @DSM

```
countDat["BRA"]

32
```

---

#### Boolean sum

```
df.country.eq('BRA').sum()
```

#### `query` + `len`

```
len(df.query('country == "BRA"')
```

#### `groupby` + `len`

```
len(df.groupby('country').groups['BRA'])
```