# Count occurrences of a single value in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, counting

I have a Series (actually the column of a DataFrame, but shouldn't matter):

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'z'])
```

I'd like to count the occurrences of `'a'` in this series. A couple of methods come to mind, starting with:

```
s.value_counts()['a']
```

The issue with this method is that it will crash for a non-existent key, while I just want a count of zero. I can also do:

```
(s == 'a').sum()
```

The issue here is that this creates a temp-array of booleans.

Does pandas have a dedicated method that allows counting the occurrences of a single value, something like `list.count`?

Comment: Maybe `value_counts` + `get`? `s.value_counts().get('a', 0)`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem. I was hoping for something with minimal temporary/unneeded data, but sure, why not.

Comment: Can't you use the `try-except` to catch the exception when you try with non-existent key?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471442/using-pandas-value-counts-to-get-one-value)?

Comment: @TonyMontana. Why bother when I can use `get`? The issue I have is with generating a whole slew of temporary data.

Comment: On small series, like yours, `sum(e=='a' for e in s)` is faster (but not on large ones)

Comment: @mozway. Thanks. That's the dupe I was looking for.

Comment: @mozway. `sum(e=='a' for e in s)` is faster than `(s == 'a').sum()`?

Comment: Does numpy have a similar function?

Comment: @QuangHoang. Not that I'm aware of. I think the numpy idiom is the sum.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes 5µs vs 270µs. Looping is often faster on small series

Comment: `sum(1 for e in s if e=='a')` is even a tiny bit faster